# Reverse tunnel from Linux box to Windows box using freeSSHd

Tags: ssh, reverse-tunnel, freesshd

I have a Linux box that is behind a NAT that I would like to get access to. Servers that I have running are using Windows. I have installed freeSSHd and can connect to the Windows server from the Linux box but I cannot get the reverse tunneling working. This is the command I am using from the Linux box:

```
ssh -R 5022:localhost:22 -p 6171 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But I get this warning:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 5022
```

Here are my settings I have set for the freeSSHd:

Authentication:
[image]

Tunneling:
[image]

There are no other processes on the Windows box that is bound to 5022

Comment: also if there is another method of reverse tunneling without ssh am all hears... or eyes

Comment: There is no question in your "question". I guess it's "how to make it work?" but please [edit] the post and explicitly ask. Asking for another method should also be added by editing, not in a comment.